# Should we install a universal question for "Where is the Play Store on <insert name of device which was usually bought in china here>?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions

*Where is the Play Store on device X?*

Is a recurring type of question related to different devices but mostly caused by the same reason which can be answered the same way.

1. See if you can root the device;
2. If root then:

   - If possible: Install Google Framework .apk;
   - If not possible: Install ROM (if exists) with Google Framework.

The questions which could be closed as duplicates of the new to create meta question, maybe marked as cw, are:

- [Google Play on a Samsung Galaxy Ace](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23877/16265)
- [Does China Mobile Galaxy S3 model GT I-9308 have Google Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24768/16265)
- [Installing official Google Marketplace on a chinese Asus Eee Pad Transformer 101](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13081/16265)
- (add more if you spot them)

What do you think?

Comment: There are quite a few similar to this relating to the Kindle Fire.

Comment: @SaintWacko Feel free to edit my post.

Comment: Alright, I can't get to it at the moment, but I'll try to add the list in when I get a chance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a fine idea for a "cannonical question". It does come up rather regularly and the solution is generically the same regardless of the device (root, install a Google apps package and/or a ROM that includes them).

My suggestion would be for the question to be entitled something like "Google Play is not pre-installed on my device, is there a way for me to install it?"

Comment: I'm in perfect agreement here. I don't think we need a question for every device.

Answer (score 3):

[I have created the question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device) and casted the closed dup votes.

Feel free to improve the cw answer. Especially the " Install the Google Apps .apk" part could be elaborated.